# Sending Logstash Jenkins Plugin data to endpoint

Tags: jenkins, logstash

I'm attempting to use the logstash Jenkins plugin to send build log data to an HTTP endpoint that just requires a sample auth token to ingest. If I was to do a basic curl command it'd look like this. If I was to do a curl command it'd look like this..

```
curl -X POST http://company/v1/collector/jenkins -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" -d '{"SAMPLE":"'12334343'"}'
```

I can format the json data as it comes in and the elastic search plugin seems to be OK but I can't seem to format the request creds. I was thinking then I could send the data to the syslog or use the TCP but I'd need some type of receiver server on the host to then forward it to my endpoint.

Options I can think of..

1. Send to syslog-ng then have syslog-ng forward to my endpoint.
2. Send data to the syslog using basic syslog from the jenkins plugin..

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity the best way to do this is to use the logstash plugin. There is an option to export elastic data, TCP data and also the ability to send to syslog.